# Solving $\frac{d^2 \theta}{d x^2} - m^2\theta = 0$ using the Ritz method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, finite-element-method, variational-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following ODE using the Ritz method:

$$\frac{d^2 \theta}{d x^2} - m^2\theta = 0$$

With the boundary conditions

$$\frac{d\theta}{dx}\Bigg{|}_{x=0} = 0$$

$$\theta(1) = \theta_0$$

I'm trying to follow the book "Conduction Heat Transfer" by Vedat S. Arpaci (chap. 8). So this is what I did so far:

1) Transform the problem into a variational problem:

$$
\int_o^1 \Bigg{(}\frac{d^2 \theta}{d x^2} - m^2\theta\Bigg{)} \delta\theta\ dx = 0
$$

2) (Ritz Method) Select a convergent sequence of functions such that

$$
y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^Na_n\phi_n(x)
$$

I choose the following $y(x)$:

$$y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N\theta_0(1 - (1 - x^2)(a_0 + a_1x^2 + a_2x^4 + ...))$$

Which yields the approximation

$$
y(x) = \phi_0(x) = \theta_0(1 - (1 - x^2)a_0)
$$

3) Apply (2) in (1) in order to obtain $a_0$

$$
\int_o^1 \Bigg{(}\frac{d^2 \theta}{d x^2} - m^2\theta\Bigg{)} \delta\theta\ dx =
$$
$$
\theta_0\int_o^1 \Bigg{(}2a_0 - m^2(1 - (1-x^2)a_0) \Bigg{)} \delta\theta\ dx = 0
$$

Where $\delta F$ is the variation of the functional $F(x, y, y^\prime)$, that is,

$$
\delta F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\delta y + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y^\prime}\delta y^\prime
$$

And this is where I got stuck. The book suggest the following:

$$
\theta_0\int_o^1 \Bigg{[}2a_0 - m^2(1 - (1-x^2)a_0) \Bigg{]} \delta\theta\ dx =
$$
$$
\theta_0\int_o^1 \Bigg{[}2a_0 - m^2(1 - (1-x^2)a_0) \Bigg{]} \Bigg{[} -(1-x^2)\delta a_0 \Bigg{]} dx = 0
$$

But I don't understand the application of $\delta \theta$ in this case, because I though $a_0$ was meant to be a constant (Should it really?), then $\theta$ is not a functional in relation to it.

Assuming $a_0$ is a function, and the step above is correct (Which I don't understand why), I would also be stuck in the next step:

$$
\theta_0\int_o^1 \Bigg{[}2a_0 - m^2(1 - (1-x^2)a_0) \Bigg{]} \Bigg{[} -(1-x^2)\delta a_0 \Bigg{]} dx = 0
$$

For this step, the book suggests to use the following identity, which I was unable to apply here:

$$
\int_0^l(l^2-x^2)^mdx = \frac{(2m)!!}{(2m+1)!!}l^{2m+1}
$$

I would be grateful for any suggestion at this point.

Comment: Is your use of $\delta$ different than $\partial$?

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I messed up the symbols. They're now fixed. $\delta$ means the variation of a functional. It is similar to differentiation, but for function of functions (a functional).

Answer (score 2):

There is something strange in your variational problem because the variational formulation for the BVP

$$
\theta''-m^2\theta = 0,\ \ \{\theta'(0)=0, \theta(1) = \theta_1\}
$$

is

$$
J[\theta] = \int_0^1 \left((\theta')^2+m^2\theta^2\right)dx,\ \ \{\theta'(0)=0, \theta(1) = \theta_1\}
$$

given an approximation for $\theta$ as

$$
\theta(x) \approx \phi_n(x) = \phi_0(x)+\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \omega_k(x)
$$

with $\phi_0(x)$ obeying the BC and $\omega_k(x)$ such that $\omega_k'(0) = \omega_k(1) = 0$ the Galerkin-Ritz formulation gives:

$$
\frac{\partial J[\phi_n]}{\partial c_k} = 0\Rightarrow \int_0^1\left(\phi_n''-m^2\phi_n\right)\omega_k dx = \phi_n'\omega_k|_0^1
$$

Choosing $\phi_0(x) = \theta_1(1-(1-x^2)c_0)$ which obeys the BC. and $\omega_k(x) = x^{k+1}(x-1),\ \ k=1,\cdots, n$ we are done.